# How to list attributes of a user in a query set

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to list users that are a member of a given group using a template tags, I'm using the code:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('perms/list-users-in-group.html')
def users_in_group(group_name):
    group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
    query = group.user_set.all()
    return {'user': query}
```

and my html snippet is

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
{% for user in users %}
    <div class="card">
        <li>{{ user.values }}</li>
        <li>{{ user|linebreaks }}</li>
        <li>{{ user.username|linebreaks }}</li>
        <li>{{ user.first_name|linebreaks }}</li>
        <li>{{ user.last_name|linebreaks }}</li>
        <li>{{ user.email|linebreaks }}</li>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The query does return a result and the list shows up on the web page however the actual data doesn't, how do you access the fields of `user` ?

Comment: I can see that you have passed `user` from your script but accessing it as `users` in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Sanip mentioned, you're not passing the right dict key to the template. Change:

```
return {'user': query}
```

To:

```
return {'users': query}
```